# using sql without any server

Tags: c++, sql

I have a question regarding SQL. Is there any way to connect to a database without a server into sql (no localhost or anything). I want to use SQL for a resource management in c++. I found the API but I need to know if that's possible, so I can use it like that.

Comment: Have you tried SQLight? http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: A moderator-deleted answer suggests [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), which is indeed everyone's favorite choice for in-process SQL.

Comment: Thank you for help! I am going to give it a try. @Jon I sqlapi++ but I dont think thats what I needed.

Comment: You can use sqlapi++ to access SQLLite.  This has the benefit that if you ever switch to a full-fledged sql database you have less to change to make that transition.

Answer (score 4):

Try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

SQLite is a sql-like database system that saves the database state to a single file somewhere on the file system, as opposed to requiring a full server. It does not have the full performance optimisations in SQL terms of full servers such as Postgres or MySQL; however, it does not require the overhead of a server.

Comment: Whilst a link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include more information. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115919/149052

Comment: Next time, go for the ad-jingle phrasing: "Don't take fright - try SQLite!"

Answer (score 0):

Theres many options, one I know of is [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142)

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174516.aspx) to microsoft's API for accessing SQL Server Compact via C++

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is really good option but the problem is its Microsoft only. I'll see if I can find cross platform alternative

Comment: @Gasim, SQLite is the cross platform alternative.

Comment: @Gasim if sqlapi++ is your api, then SQL Server compact might not be an option.  You might want to add that to your question if thats an important constraint.  With a properly written cross platform api, theres no inherent limitation to using SQL Server compact.

Comment: @Gasim similiarly, if cross-platform engine is a constraint that would be something to add to your question